# How to transform dates in Y-m format without days

Tags: r

I have a data vector that looks like this:

```
dates<-c("2014-11", "2014-12", "2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03", "2015-04")
```

I am trying to convert it into a recognizable date format, however no luck:

```
as.Date(dates,"%Y-%m")
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I suspect that the problem lies in that that there is no day specified.

Any thoughs of how this can be solved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **zoo** package has a nice interface to this, which allows storing of year-month data and a `as.Date` method to coerce to a `Date` object. For example:

```
library("zoo")
dates <- c("2014-11", "2014-12", "2015-01", "2015-02", "2015-03", "2015-04")
```

The function to convert the character vector or year-months into a `yearmon` is `as.yearmon`. The second argument is the format of the date parts in the individual strings. Here I use

- `%Y` for year with century
- `%m` for the month as a decimal
- Separated by literal `-`

.

```
yrmo <- as.yearmon(dates, "%Y-%m")
```

This gives

```
> yrmo
[1] "Nov 2014" "Dec 2014" "Jan 2015" "Feb 2015" "Mar 2015" "Apr 2015"
```

This is actually the default, so you can leave off the format part entirely, e.g. `yrmo <- as.yearmon(dates)`

To convert to a `Date` class object, the `as.Date` method is used

```
> as.Date(yrmo)
[1] "2014-11-01" "2014-12-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-02-01" "2015-03-01"
[6] "2015-04-01"
```

This method has a second argument `frac` which is specified allows you to state how far through the month you want each resulting `Date` element to be (how many days as a fraction of the length of the month in days)

```
> as.Date(yrmo, frac = 0.5)
[1] "2014-11-15" "2014-12-16" "2015-01-16" "2015-02-14" "2015-03-16"
[6] "2015-04-15"
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

If we need to convert to `Date` class, it needs a day.  So, we can `paste` with one of the days of interest, say 1, and use `as.Date`

```
as.Date(paste0(dates, "-01"))
```

Comment: got it, it works. Thanks!